# Socket.io disconnecting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, express

I have a chat done in nodejs, Express, socket.io and angular. It works well but disconnects sometimes and at random times. Generally the connection lasts no more than 2 minutes. I get several net :: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on the console.

PS.: I'm using apache 2.2 on CentOS with certified ssl.
Any tips?

My server.js header is below

```js
#!/bin/env node

var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
app = express(),
logger = require('morgan'),
_m = require("./models/Message"),
Message = _m.m,
NewMessage = _m.n,
Group = _m.g,
Online = _m.o,
DeletedMessage = _m.d,
LastMessage = _m.l,
_mTASK = require("./models/Task"),
_Task = _mTASK.t,
TaskComment = _mTASK.c,
TaskLog = _mTASK.l,
TaskModel = _mTASK.m,
TaskNotification = _mTASK.n,
_d = require("./lib/Connection");

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('ipaddr', "127.0.0.1");

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ipaddr'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on  IP: ' + app.get('ipaddr') + ' and port ' + app.get('port'));
});


var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.set("origins", 'https://meusite.me:*');
io.set('transports', ['polling', 'websocket']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A bit of socket.io background**

Server sends a heartbeat to the client every X seconds where X == the 
`heartbeat interval` configuration value.

If the client fails to respond, socket considers the connect dead

Client waits for a heartbeat from the server every N seconds where N == the `heartbeat timeout` configuration value.

Both of these values are set on the server with `heartbeat timeout` being sent to the client when an individual connection is opened.

Given the file above, you could set the `heartbeat timeout` with something like ...

```js
//WARNING io.set() has been depricated

var io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.set('heartbeat interval', '30000');
io.set('heartbeat timeout', '45000');
io.set("origins", 'https://meusite.me:*');
io.set('transports', ['polling', 'websocket']);

//Setting your server configuration is now done via ..

var socket = require('socket.io')({
  // options go here
  'configOption': 'configValue';
});
```